# How UI frameworks/libraries parse code in HTML tags

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm curious to know how frameworks such as Angular convert text in the markup to JavaScript. For example:

```
<h2>Products</h2>

<div *ngFor="let product of products">

  <h3>
    <a [title]="product.name + ' details'">
      {{ product.name }}
    </a>
  </h3>

</div>
```

How is the above processed so `product.name + ' details'` is converted to JavaScript code `product.name`, considering that in the above code `product.name` is coded as a string.
In a sense, I'm wondering how an HTML attribute value is parsed and converted to JavaScript code.
This question is not just about Angular but more of a general question as how JavaScript libraries/frameworks process the embedded code in HTML tags?

Comment: I think it depends on the framework's mechanism itself  
here's some resources that might be useful
for angular it's called data binding: 
https://dzone.com/articles/data-binding-in-angular
https://indepth.dev/posts/1129/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular

Comment: React uses hooks and states

Comment: Thanks for your responses but my question is rather independent of the framework/library. What I wonder about is how parsing/processing of the code is done so the what is written as a string (i.e. "Product.name + 'details'") is interpreted/converted to JavaScript?